# How to set JMenu Foreground color using UIManager

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jmenu, uimanager

I am trying to set JMenu foreground color in my project.
I use **UIManager.put("text", Color.RED)** it work for all text but in JMenu text color does not change.

I want to set **JMenu.setForeground("Color.RED")** to work but **UIManager.put("Menu.foreground", Color.RED)** does not fill color.
So please help me for this below code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Frame() {
    setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setTitle("MENU COLOR");
    initComponents();
}
private void initComponents() {

    menu_bar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    jMenu1.setText("File");
    jMenu1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("URW Bookman L", 0, 18));
    jMenu1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(45, 25));
    jMenu1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    menu_bar.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(menu_bar);

    pack();
}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
                    .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    UIManager.put("Menu.foreground", Color.RED);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackStrace();
        } 
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Frame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menu_bar;

}
```

Thank You For Reading

Comment: should use Menu.background but that doesnt seem to work for me either. Good question

Comment: I did only `jMenu1.setForeground(Color.RED);` It works fine. File Menu text is set to red.

Comment: yes, but I want to use **UIManager.put("Menu.foreground", Color.RED)** this for set foreground color of JMenu.

Comment: For future reference, whenever posting a Swing MCVE, make sure you call `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`, so that we don't end up with a million background programs (like I just did right now :-), when testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace a separate component UI.

Example:

```
public class MyMenuUI extends SynthMenuUI {


  public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent aComponent) {
    return new MyMenuUI();
  }

  @Override
  public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    c.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Menu.foreground"));
  }
}
```

After initialization of L&F you must simply put your UI into L&F

```
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager
                .getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                UIManager.put("Menu.foreground", Color.RED);
                UIManager.put("MenuUI", MyMenuUI.class.getName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackStrace();
    }
```

Disadvantage: you must do it for each supported L&F

Comment: @HArdik I've modified my example